# not able to access demo app after starting tomee

Tags: tomcat

When starting tomee on the dos command prompt, I get this output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002] 
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Hockchai>C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0.1\bin\startup.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0.1"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0.1"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0.1\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "c:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre7"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0.1\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache
-tomee-plus-1.6.0.1\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

When I try to access the demo app: `http://localhost:8080/`, I get the not able to connect error.  I don't see anything in the logs folder.  Is there something that I can do to see what is causing it to not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after I change JRE_HOME from c:\PROGRA~2\java\jre7 to c:\PROGRA~2\java\jre6.  Strange...